# Realm: Updating objects keeping previous values

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to update a list of objects keeping those objects that have been modified.

The way I'm trying to achieve this is by:

1. Getting the modified items and keeping them to later re-insert them in the list.
2. Clear the list.
3. Add the new objects (from the server).
4. Reinsert the previously separated subgroup of object (step 1).

```
    RealmResults list = r.where(ExampleObject.class)
        .equalTo("state", VAR.STATE.MODIFIED).or()
        .equalTo("state", VAR.STATE.CLOSED)
        .findAll();
    
    r.where(ExampleObject.class)
        .equalTo("state", VAR.STATE.ORIGINAL)
        .findAll()
        .clear();
    
    r.copyToRealmOrUpdate(result); // here, list becomes 0!!!
    r.copyToRealmOrUpdate(list);
```

## The problem:

When I add the new data all the objects get rewritten making those that had been modified (`STATE.MODIFIED`) become `STATE.ORIGINAL`.

**Is there any way to keep the values from the objects stored locally?**

All of this is to avoid looping the entire list manually

Comment: What is the `result` in `r.copyToRealmOrUpdate(result);` ?

Comment: the `result` is the new data (from server)

Comment: For now (Realm v0.88.3), the `RealmResults` will be automatically updated if there is a modification to the db in the same handler loop. So if the `result` contains the sames objects in the `list`, the `list` will be updated according to the data changed in the `results`. However, this behaviour will be changed in PR https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2124. You can check the details in the PR message.